# Creating links in same html page

Tags: html

On my page I have few categories and some content for each

1. japanese food

   some content
2. American food

   some content
3. Japanese food

   some content

On top I want to show link for each of this label

Click to Link : Japanese food , american food, Italian food

How can I do it?

Comment: @NicolòMonili — That's horribly out of date. It says "A slightly more modern way", for the approach which has been standard for almost two decades and which is supported by everything newer than Netscape 4.

Answer (score 5):

Give the element you want to link to an `id`. Then put `href="#the_id"`.

e.g.

```
<a href="#japanese">Japanese food</a>
<!-- etc -->
<section id="japanese">
    <h2>Japanese food</h2>
    <p>some content</p>
</section>
```